# Yet another Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> An invading force was once named my prefix
>   What they left after, colored my suffix
>   Forgetting my infix is just not allowed
>   When applied to people, I'm more than a crowd

What am I?

Hint:

> The 3rd line is a cultural reference to '90s American music, but you should be able to solve this riddle with only the other 3 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it maybe a

> hundred?

An invading force was once named my prefix

> the Huns

What they left after, colored my suffix

> red (blood)

When applied to people, I'm more than a crowd

> like, a hundred people is a lot? Not sure about this one :D

Comment: Correct!  Do you have any guesses as to the 3rd line?

Comment: @Ertai87 Not a clue :)

Comment: rot13: sbetbg nobhg qer

Comment: You were faster

Comment: I deleted my comment so you can have it :)